# Net force on the side of a jar

Tags: integration, geometry, physics

A round conical flask is filled with water of a depth $h$. The radius of the upper water surface is $R_1$ and that of the lower
surface is $R_2$.

- What is the net force that the water exerts on the sides
  of the flask?
- What is the force on the bottom of the flask?
- What is the sum of these forces?

Ignore atmospheric pressure.

[image]

I know the force on the bottom is:

$$F = pgh\pi R_2^2$$
since $F$ is the pressure times cross section area and pressure is $pgh$.

However, I don’t know how to find the force on the sides of the jar. I think some integration is involved.

Comment: Hint: will the flask move if you put it on a smooth horizontal surface?

Comment: I thnik itegrating the pressure on the whole side maybe gives the answer but I am not sure

Comment: You don't need to integrate.

Comment: @RobertIsrael the flask will not move

Comment: So the net force on the sides is ...

Comment: but there is some force due to pressure on the flask

Comment: I have the book answer is 1/3pghpi(2r^2-r1^2-r1*r2)

Comment: The force on one side is cancelled by the force other side.

Comment: the problem is asking for the net force on the sides of the jar not the net force on the object

Comment: Oh, sorry, the net force on the sides is upwards.  The difference between the force from pressure on the bottom and the weight of the water.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I dont understand, why is that true?

Comment: Let the jar rest on a table. Then the flask is not accelerating, so the net force on the whole flask -- consisting of the net upward force on the sides, the downward force on the bottom from water pressure, the downward force of gravity due to the flask's own weight, and the upward force of the table supporting the weight of the flask plus the weight of the water -- must be zero.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But due to the fact that the net force on the sides is asked first, I suspect that it was meant to be integrated after all, although the sum of forces can be used to check the integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radius $r$ of the flask at the water depth $l$ is
$$ r= r_1+\frac{l}h(r_2-r_1)$$
Let $\theta $ be the side slant angle of the flask. Over the depth $dl$, the area $dA$ of the flask is
$$dA= \frac{2\pi r}{\cos \theta}dl$$
Per the symmetry, the horizontal force exerted on the side of the flask neutralizes, while vertical force exerted over the area $dA$ is
\begin{align}
dF &=p g l \sin\theta dA=2\pi pg\tan\theta \ lrdl\\
&= 2\pi pg\frac{r_2-r_1}{h}l\left[r_1+\frac{l}h(r_2-r_1)\right]dl
\end{align}
Then, the total net force is integrated over the water depth $h$
\begin{align}
F& =\int_0^h dF= 2\pi pg\frac{r_2-r_1}{h} \int_0^h\left[lr_1+\frac{l^2}h(r_2-r_1)\right]dl\\
&= 2\pi pg\frac{r_2-r_1}{h} \left[\frac12r_1h^2+\frac{h^2}3( r_2-r_1)\right]=\frac\pi3 pgh(2r_2^2-r_1^2-r_1r_2)
\end{align}

Comment: How did you find the radius at lenght l seems like you are taking some kind of avarage

Comment: what is the formual for area of the flask?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts - $r(l)$ is linear, with $r(0)=r_1$ and $r(h)=r_2$

Comment: what about dF  formula why is sin there?

Comment: Also I woud like that you elaborate more on the derivation of the dA of the flask

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts - The element area of the flask within $dl$ is $2\pi r\cdot \frac {dl}{\cos\theta}$, where $\frac {dl}{\cos\theta}$ is the element length of the flask at the  angle $\theta$.

Comment: when I differentiate I get $$dA =\frac{2\pi(r2-r1)}{cos\theta }dl$$ Thats when i PLUG in the fromula  for r in the the formula for area

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts - $dA$ is the area of a circular ring with radius $r$ and width $dl/\cos\theta$

Comment: what does cosine represent I get dl  is the width why the cosine?

Comment: I am open to a zoom call

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts - $dl$ is height, while $dl/\cos \theta$ is the width of the corresponding circular ring due to its conical angle $\theta$. Note that if the flask is a cylinder, its width is simply $dl$.

Comment: I finally understand but one last question in the area I think it dl/cos is thickness not widht?

Comment: also when you replace tan in the function why you put (r2-r1/h) instead of l/h

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts - $\theta$ is btw the side and the vertical, which leads to $\tan\theta=(r_2-r_1)/h$

Comment: Ah I see the opposite r2-r1 and adyacent h, I was thinking in the slope in the linear equation thank you sir